# Consuming Biztalk 2006 R2 Orchestration exposed as a web service

Tags: web-services, biztalk, orchestration

I have created an Orchestration which is exposed as a web service, the Orchestration basically receives an message type of employee, which has the Employee_Name promoted as a distinguised field to which I assign the value as below to the ModifiedEmployeeMsg in a Message assignment shape and send the ModifiedEmployeeMsg to the response part of the Soap Adapter.

modifiedEmployeeMsg = employeeMsg; modifiedEmployeeMsg.EmployeeName = "Sam";

Now, I want to consume this exposed web service from a Windows application, can you tell me the process how can I call this web service and how I need to pass the XML message as a parameter to the web service, basically its a synchronous call to the web service where I pass the employee msg and the modified version of the employee message back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the web service as you would any web service.

This would involve adding a web reference to your Windows application.  This will generate proxy objects in your Windows application (e.g. EmployeeMsg) that allow you to invoke the service without constructing any XML.  .NET will manage all of the XML for you.

This article on MSDN, [Consuming Web Services with the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446547.aspx), has an example.  Just ignore the Compact Framework intro -- the rest of article still applies.

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to publish the orchestration as a web service using the BizTalk Web Services Publishing Wizard. After that consuming the web service is like consuming any other typical web service. For more details you might want to visit this link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561809(BTS.10).aspx